# How to use Record Type for this specific question

Tags: custom-object, record-type, object, create-records

I am in the process of adding a new object to my org. I am unsure how to store all the information I need on this object.

I need to have 5 sections every time I update this object:

- 3 sections that will all be checkboxes to mark off.
- 2 text fields in every section of the 5.

I don't want to repeat the example of the field

- ‘Comments A” for section 1 and
- ‘Commented B” for section 2.

That does not make sense. All the fields' names are the same in each section beside the main field to what the section is about. Every time I go on this object I would need to populate each and every one of these fields in each section.

What am I looking to do? I am thinking I should be using record types. However, I am not sure what the steps are to achieve this. I see that perhaps I should make an object for each section but I don't think that makes sense either. Each of the sections does not need its own object. It is all connected to one main object.

For an example :

Object - evaluation

```
Section 1   Section 2
Q1              Q1
Q2              Q2
Q3              Q3
Q4              Q4 


Section 3   Section 4
Q1               Q1
Q2               Q2
Q3               Q3
Q4               Q4 

Section 5   
Q1          
Q2                   
Q3                    
Q4
```

How can I create something like this in salesforce? As of now, this is something we would do in google forms. so we are trying to optimize and use salesforce more.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!
I am looking forward to hearing from you. :)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).   The answer to your question is "it depends".  Take a look at [Building Forms](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/build-forms) decision guide, it goes over the options.  In addition to the options listed there, have a look at [Surveys](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/get-started-with-salesforce-surveys). Surveys work for a lot form-based use cases.

Comment: Sounds like a parent object with a related list of master detail child object records.